# Address autocomplete/suggest API

Tags: api, geo-location

I am looking for services that provide API to get list of suggestions for given part of address like:

`GET http://example.com/suggest?q=Mosc` ->

```
{'suggestions': ['Russia, Moscow, Moscow',
                 'Russia, Moscow',
                 'Russia, Moscow Oblast',
                 'Greece, Moschato, Moschato-Tavros',
                 'Greece, Moschato, Moschato']}
```

The only one I have found is [HERE](https://developer.here.com/documentation/geocoder-autocomplete/dev_guide/topics/quick-start-get-suggestions.html), but I am looking for other options. I don't have any requirements (paid service is OK).

Comment: A world wide search is probably a bit much. Would a solution with a starting location and a radius be ok? When searching for "Mosc", the results will likely be thousands, like every bus station, every street, every sight seeing in Moscow. Is that what you need?

Comment: @ThomasWeller yes, it's ok to have a starting point. I am open to your suggestions. If a service gives me thousands of results, I will probably find a way to limit them to meet my needs.

Comment: It's likely more the other way round: if an API request produces too much data, it might take a long time to process and a) the connection times out or b) the result is truncated or c) it takes a long time to transmit. My approach would be a similar to [this one](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/73957/consistent-address-generator/73959#73959), using OpenStreetMap data. I'll try to come up with a solution that is close to your request, but it may take some time.

Comment: @ThomasWeller excellent! Patiently waiting for your response.